# Finding the comma, where is it coming from? Javascript Arrays within Objects

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Ok so i have hacked something together it works as intended but I get a comma between entries more than one.

I have this

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  let markup = '';

  markup = `
    <section>
      <div class="inner-element">

        <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 bg-purple-800">
          <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">HCP365 Pixels</span>
          <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.sitePixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.searchPixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.emailPixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.programmaticPixels.map((x) => x)}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-element">

        <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 bg-gray-500">
          <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">NON HCP365 Pixels</span>
          <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.map((x) => x)}
        </div>
      </div>
  `;

  markup += '</section>';

  sendResponse(markup);
});
```

Which in turn gives me this:

[image]

Where the little bugger is here:

[image]

Between the element which is :

```js
const pixelInfo = `
    <div class="element">

      <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 ${colorGrade}">
        <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">${pixelType}</span>
        <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="answer hideText">
        <span id="pixel-url" class="c-word-wrap text-sm font-mono">${pixelUrl}</span>
          <span id="query-params">${queryParams}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
```

Each `pixelInfo` is pushed into it's own array which is within an object. Is this comma here because I am mapping through an array and it's chucking out the `,` ? Is there a way to get rid of it?

This is my whole code

```js
const HCP365Object = {
  sitePixels: [],
  searchPixels: [],
  emailPixels: [],
  programmaticPixels: [],
  nonHCP365Pixels: [],
};

// Function to break down the http request into our pixel url with a subset of associating query params.
const onBeforeSendHeadersListener = function (details) {
  let regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
    pixelType,
    pixelUrl = `${details.url}`,
    queryParams,
    params = {},
    match,
    colorGrade;

  if (details.url.includes('&ch=1&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Site Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-600';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=2&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Search Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-500';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=3&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Email Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-400';
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=4&')) {
    pixelType = 'HCP365 Programmatic Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-purple-300';
  } else {
    pixelType = 'Non HCP365 PP Pixel';
    colorGrade = 'bg-gray-400';
  }

  // Splitting url's query params out to key value pairs
  while ((match = regex.exec(details.url))) {
    params[match[1]] = match[2];
  }

  // Looping through object's key value pair to place into divs
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    queryParams += `
      <div class="text-sm my-1">
        <span class="font-bold uppercase mr-1">${key}: </span>
        <span class="font-normal font-mono capitalize c-word-wrap">${value}</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  const pixelInfo = `
    <div class="element">

      <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 ${colorGrade}">
        <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">${pixelType}</span>
        <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="answer hideText">
        <span id="pixel-url" class="c-word-wrap text-sm font-mono">${pixelUrl}</span>
          <span id="query-params">${queryParams}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  // push the relevant pixel into the correct array
  if (details.url.includes('&ch=1&')) {
    HCP365Object.sitePixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=2&')) {
    HCP365Object.searchPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=3&')) {
    HCP365Object.emailPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else if (details.url.includes('&ch=4&')) {
    HCP365Object.programmaticPixels.push(pixelInfo);
  } else {
    HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.push(pixelInfo);
  }

  return HCP365Object;
};

// Apply the function entered to each header coming from contextweb domain
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  onBeforeSendHeadersListener,
  {
    urls: ['https://*.contextweb.com/bh/*'],
  },
  ['requestHeaders']
);

// Initiate connection to send Message over to popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  let markup = '';

  markup = `
    <section>
      <div class="inner-element">

        <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 bg-purple-800">
          <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">HCP365 Pixels</span>
          <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.sitePixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.searchPixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.emailPixels.map((x) => x)}
          ${HCP365Object.programmaticPixels.map((x) => x)}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-element">

        <div class="question flex justify-between px-6 py-4 bg-gray-500">
          <span class="text-base text-white font-bold">NON HCP365 Pixels</span>
          <button><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.map((x) => x)}
        </div>
      </div>
  `;

  markup += '</section>';

  sendResponse(markup);
});
```

I know it's very hacky! But it works

Comment: map returns an array and you guess you are forcing the template to do toString() on the array so you would get commas between items. You probably want `.....map(...).join('')`

Comment: using`.join('')` fixed it thanks man~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking another look at

```
markup = `
    ...

         <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.map((x) => x)}
        </div>

    ...
`;
```

The problem is `HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.map((x) => x)`. `map()` returns an array, and calling `toString()` will list all items separated by commas.

You will need to `join()` these to build the content without the commas.

Also, since `.map((x) => x)` just returns a copy of the array you can get rid of that too.

```
markup = `
    ...

        <div class="answer hideText">
          ${HCP365Object.nonHCP365Pixels.join('')}
        </div>

    ...
`;
```

You should use `.join('')` everywhere you use `.map((x) => x)`